Handrail type and locations for my staircase rebuild
I tore my whole balustrade apart in order to install new flooring on our stairs. We had the intention of also eliminating the wall rail on the opposite side where there’s a full length wall. This idea seems to be reinforced by many of our inspiration photos (see first 2 attached images).


Well, I’ve got this unique situation at the top of my stairs where there is a small section with walls on both sides of the stairs. I was just about to place an order for a bunch of custom materials when I realized my plans would result in someone descending down the stairs with nothing to grab onto for the first 3-4 stairs.
My stairs so far:

Section with walls on both sides at the top:

What am I supposed to do here? My original plan was for the main handrail (balustrade) to butt directly into the drywall at the top (on a separate note, I did research on how to do so without the need for a rosette or half-newel). Now I’m wondering if I need to custom shape some sort of gooseneck offset where the handrail resting on top of all the iron balusters somehow transitions into a wall rail at the top section (see marked up images attached).


Or does this unique scenario mean that I have to sacrifice the idea of eliminating the huge existing wall rail, meaning I will end up with 2 full length rails on both sides of the stairs?
Please don’t mind the gaps on the sides of my treads and risers. I opted to go the route of doing scribed skirting boards instead of butting treads and risers to a solid piece of stock. I’ve constantly chosen the masochistic path every step of the way on this project. 
Please let me know your opinions and expertise! Thanks in advance y’all! 

This question illustrates well why I despise home improvement television. It gives you the impression that carpentry is easy, and it glosses over many important details. The second handrail is there for a good reason, but it would interfere with the impression intended by marketing images.

As others have indicated, you need a continuously grippable (slidable) handrail. This can be done as you've drawn in the second-to-last image, by connecting a wall-mounted rail to a baluster-supported one, but be warned: this is expert-level carpentry. Making all those angles and lines come together at the proper height and in a robust fashion is no simple thing. I'd expect it would take me a week to build that to a professional standard, even having done similar work many times in life. Note that the offset should really be 45 deg. angles, not 90, and you need to maintain backside clearance.

Code requires a continuous handrail from the first to the last step. Your idea in green where the wall rail intersects with the handrail could serve as that. I have seen that condition work in the past, but the code may have changed since then.
Even though it is not a true continuous handrail, but sort of an interrupted one, or perhaps another way to look at it is an intersected one. In my opinion, now matter what you call it, is a viable option. You truly do need a wall rail to finish the run on that side, or you would need to go back with what you had to start with.

Actually, if you want to be technical, the OG rail doesn't meet code either—it ends before (or starts after, depending on your direction) the bottom step!

You need at least 1 rail on all stairs.  You will either need to add the circled green section or maintain some of the wooden rail on the right.
I bought a house that looked much like yours, with the green section, with a section as if your black child/pet gate were rails at the top of the landing, and nothing on the wall.  This meant no place to hold on for much of the ascent descent.  I added a rail on the wall here as yours is shown, but not all the way to the bottom, there was some overlap to the green section.  If I were you I would leave the wooden rail on the right in place.
I looked at the codes back then & my recollection is they were of minimal help and do not specify such things as how to achieve continuous coverage.
